# How to change default endline in Python email.mime

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline, mime-types

When I am using the mime module, I would like to change the default end line (which is `\n`)

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
a = MIMEText('hello')
a['From'] = 'stack'
print(a.as_bytes())
```

The result is

```
b'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\nFrom: stack\n\nhello'
```

However, I want to use this in an HTTP request (the reason is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746558/)), so I need to change the separating `\n` to `\r\n`. Is there any ways to implement that?